# ngSanitize preserve <script> tags

Tags: angularjs, xss

I want to render this -

`<b>Hello</b> World, <script>alert("xss")</script>`

as -

> **Hello** World, <script>alert("xss")</script>

While, currently with ngSanitize, and using `ng-bind-html`, it renders as

> **Hello** World,

I don't want to completely strip script tag, but not execute it as html(while executing the safe html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is made impossible by design. You cannot decorate `ngSanitize` to accept `<script>` tags. If you look at other directives that need special or extended `ngSanitize` functionality they provide their own replacement. For example [**text-angular**](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular).

---

**Warning, at your own risk!**

If you really, really need to accept `<script>` tags and runnable JS, open the `angular-sanitize.js` file and look for

```
var blockedElements = toMap('script,style');
```

around line 268 in v1.6.9. Replace that with

```
var blockedElements = toMap('style');
```

Now you must add `script` to the list of inline elements, in v1.6.9 around line 255

```
var inlineElements = extend({}, optionalEndTagInlineElements, toMap('a,abbr,acronym,b,script,' + ...
```

Finally you must avoid sanitize to translate chars like `(` and `{` into hex entities. Look for `function encodeEntities(value) {` around line 478, comment out

```
/*
replace(NON_ALPHANUMERIC_REGEXP, function(value) {
  return '&#' + value.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
}).
*/
```

Now `<b>Hello</b> World, <script>alert("xss")</script>` will be accepted and `alert("xss")` will be triggered when the page load.